# Is `cond ? true : false` ever good syntax?

Tags: javascript, c#

Starting a new job and my coworkers' code is littered with `cond ? true : false` expressions in their C# and Javascript code.  My inclination would be to replace all these occurrences with `cond`.  But the code doesn't have enough regression tests to be too incredibly bold while refactoring, so I'm cautious.  I even noticed this pattern in a Javascript library we use, which made me wonder if this is ever good syntax.  To my eye, it just looks like someone forgot that `bool` expressions are already values and we don't need to whip out the `bool` literals.  I'm pretty confident that I can always pull this out of the C# code, but I wonder if the Javascript conditional operator plays with coercion at all?  Or if there's any other reason why this pattern can sometimes be good practice?

Comment: So are you asking about C# or Javascript code, because the two are not the same.

Comment: It's "good" in that it works, but it's pointless generally. Riskier to fix in JavaScript because of language semantics.

Comment: @Servy - The OP clearly knows that they are not the same. See the end of the question...

Comment: @JoshCrozier Yes, the OP suspects they aren't the same.  I don't know which one they're asking about though.

Comment: This seems like a case where something that might make some sense in one language (javascript) is just being reused in another where it doesn't (C#).

Comment: @juharr although admittedly far fetched, C# can behave exactly the same way, it just depends on how the involved types are implemented; see my answer.

Comment: @InBetween Very nice.  I honestly didn't even know those operators existed, but I guess the same would apply if you setup an implicit cast to `bool` as well.

Comment: @juharr The subtle difference is that with an implicit cast `cond` *is* a `bool` and the expression is useless. In the example I provide, you actually *need* to use that seemingly senseless expression if you want to extract the "boolean state" of the instance to use it somewhere else; a method call expecting a boolean argument for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have answered your question already.

I agree with you that you can safely pull this out of the C# code. The `?:` operator can only have a boolean as its first operand and the compiler takes care of ensuring it. So even without enough tests I would feel confident of the result. On the other hand, handling `cond ? false : true` would be a little trickier but not much.

JS code is another beast. It may be possible to have the following case in your code:

```js
var cond = 1;
var boolean = cond ? true : false;

// somewhere far from the assignment or not easy to visualize
if (boolean === true) {
  console.log("it was true!");
} else {
  console.log("it was false!");
}
```

Which will behave differently if you blindly replace the ternary operator.

```js
var cond = 1;
var boolean = cond;

// somewhere far from the assignment or not easy to visualize
if (boolean === true) {
  console.log("it was true!");
} else {
  console.log("it was false!");
}
```

In any case, I would first talk with the team and understand the reason behind the usage of this construct. Maybe there is a good (although weird) reason behind it.

Answer (score 4):

All the answers stating that `cond ? true : false` is redundant code in C# are not entirely correct. There is a a little known/used language feature where it actually makes sense (although it is more than likely that this is not your particular case).

Consider the following type:

```
class StrangeWrapper<T>
{
    public T Value { get; }
    public StrangeWrapper(T value) { Value = value; }

    public static bool operator true(StrangeWrapper<T> value)
    {
        return !Equals(value.Value, default(T));
    }

    public static bool operator false(StrangeWrapper<T> value)
    {
        return Equals(value.Value, default(T));
    }
}
```

Now you can do the following:

```
var t = new StrangeWrapper<int>(1);
var f = new StrangeWrapper<string>(null);
var thisWillBeTrue = t ? true : false;
var thisWillBeFalse = f ? true : false;
```

Not that I consider this use case particularly useful, but the little know feature is that `cond` need not be a `bool`; it can be *any* type that implements the [`true`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x6y6z4d.aspx) and [`false`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6292hy1k.aspx) operators.

Comment: Because yes, there is always 1 way to break the code in a bizarre way, you are that guy aren't you? LoL. I thoroughly enjoyed your example! XD

Comment: @Coolio Thanks! xD. Never say never when it comes to programming languages...even the most seemingly useless construct can have its use in very specific conditions.

Comment: Awesome! I will to try this operator in my code just to annoy my coworkers (and maybe get fired). In any case, the type of thisWillBeTrue is bool, and after removing the ternary operator its type will be StrangeWrapper<T>, so the compiler will complain if any other part of the code is expecting a bool. That is what I meant for "safe to replace".

Answer (score 2):

I can only speak for the javascript side, but you did not provide enough information on how `cond?true: false` is used. In other words: is the boolean value of the expression being set to a variable? - and that variable used elsewhere? Or is the expression only evaluated within an if statement?

I ask because javascript is an untyped language.

If every instance of `cond` is a boolean true or false, then sure, replace them.

If any instance of `cond` is maybe a string or an int this could change the way the program functions.

A simple example:

```
var cond = "helloworld"
var bool = cond?true:false
console.log(bool)
```

//^Where printing bool will print `true`

Where as:

```
var cond = "helloworld"
console.log(cond);
```

//^where printing cond would result in the string `helloworld`

So in javascript, depending on how stuff is used, replacing these expressions with `cond` may not be the best solution.

One thing you can do to minimize the eyesore is change `cond?true:false` to `!!cond`. It is doing the same thing but with less text.  The downside being it isn't always immediately clear what you're doing.

Where ! is the not operator and !! essentially returns the Boolean value of the imputed value.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it really has value for both c# and js 
For js as it is not type safe this is equivalent to new boolean (cond)

It also makes all non 1 and true values equal to false without dealing with Nan and null

In C# if the object is dynamic type it would be the same case as js

If it is a bool then you just avoid runtime errors which is a bad practice from my point of view